# how can i hook if return type is a list<string> in xposed?

Tags: java, android, xposed, xposed-framework

here is my code...can't figure out how should be the return type written

```
  if (lpparam.packageName.equals("com.demo.data")) {
        XposedBridge.log("we are in Module!");      

        findAndHookMethod("com.demo.data.utils.Utils", lpparam.classLoader, "getListFromJsonArrayString", List<String>,new XC_MethodHook() {
            @Override
            protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                XposedBridge.log("we are in method!");
                log("call -> " + (String) param.getResult());
            }
        });
    }


List<String> or List<String.class> is not working
```

The method that i am trying to hook is having return type of

```
  List<string> getListFromJsonArrayString()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem:

```
findAndHookMethod(..., "getListFromJsonArrayString", List<String>, new XC_MethodHook() {
```

The type list here is for the **parameter** types. You should not have the return type here (not to mention that this isn't valid Java, you probably meant `List.class`). The correct form should be:

```
findAndHookMethod(..., "getListFromJsonArrayString", new XC_MethodHook() {
```

This is unambiguous, since you cannot have two Java methods with the same name and parameter type list with different return types.

Second problem:

```
log("call -> " + (String) param.getResult());
```

The return type is a `List<String>`. You are casting it to a `String`, which will obviously not work. Correct form:

```
log("call -> " + (List<String>) param.getResult());
```

Note that this will show an unchecked cast warning, but since you know exactly what the generic type is, you can ignore it.